# How to target the 7th child only

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, mura

**Problem** I have the following code that displays the navigation bar that is provided by Mura:

```
#$.dspPrimaryNav(
viewDepth=0
, id='navPrimary'
, class='nav navbar-nav nav-nowrap'
, displayHome='never'
, closeFolders=false 
, showCurrentChildrenOnly=false
, liHasKidsClass='dropdown'
, liHasKidsAttributes=''
, liCurrentClass=''
, liCurrentAttributes=''
, liHasKidsNestedClass='dropdown-submenu'
, aHasKidsClass='dropdown-toggle'
, aHasKidsAttributes='role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" data-target="##"'
, aCurrentClass=''
, aCurrentAttributes=''
, ulNestedClass='dropdown-menu'
, ulNestedAttributes=''
, aNotCurrentClass=''
, siteid=$.event('siteid')
)#
```

And the displays the following navigation bar:
[image]

As you can see above, the second row of the navigation bar is shifted to the right. I tried the following css to align the second row with the first row of the navigation bar:

```
#navPrimary ul:nth-child(3n+1){
    margin-left:-15px;
}
```

However, it is not working. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I would suggest you to create fiddle for your problem.

Comment: Are you trying to target the seventh element specifically, or the first element that line-wraps your navbar? (which may not be the 7th one, depending on window / font size)

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following css to target the 7th item of the list. I assume all of the links are part of the same list so I changed the ul to li.

```
#navPrimary li:nth-child(7){
    margin-left:-15px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`:nth-child(N)` psuedo selector, where N = sequence of the child, can select the child node of an element. To select 7th child us N=7 in your selector. Solution to your problem been-

```
#navPrimary ul li:nth-child(7){
  // Your style rules here...
}
```

Reference: [CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/how-nth-child-works/)

Comment: This would target the 7th `ul`. Also, you have an extra `:` in your selector.

Comment: I was bit sleepy... :D